# Открытие страницы и вывод значения

Tags: javascript

У меня есть генератор паролей для регистраций на сайте, я его хочу переделать в генератор ссылок для своего сайта, чтобы при нажатии "генерировать" он открывал новую страницу и выдавал ссылку со сгенерированным адресом вида: `http://*****.ру/` (значение генератора)

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript" SRC="1.js"></SCRIPT> 
<center>
<table width=80% border=0>
<tr align=center>
<td>
<form name="myform">
<table border=0>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#B7DADB">
1-й элемент может быть:
</td>
<td bgcolor="#B7DADB">
<input type=checkbox name=firstNumber checked>Цифра
<input type=checkbox name=firstLower checked>Прописная
<input type=checkbox name=firstUpper checked>Заглавная
<input type=checkbox name=firstOther>Другие элементы
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#D4D4D4">
Последующие элементы:
</td>
<td bgcolor="#D4D4D4">
<input type=checkbox name=latterNumber checked>Цифра
<input type=checkbox name=latterLower checked>Прописная
<input type=checkbox name=latterUpper checked>Заглавная
<input type=checkbox name=latterOther>Другие элементы
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#999999">
Длина пароля:
</td>
<td bgcolor="#999999">
<input type=text name=passwordLength value="8" size=3>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#999999">
Доп. элементы: 
</td>
<td bgcolor="#999999">
<input type=text name=extraChars size=20>
</td>
</tr>
</font>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#999999">
<font size="4" color="#FFFFFF">Новый пароль:
</font>
</td>
<font size="4" color="#FF0000">
<td bgcolor="#999999">
<font size="4" color="#FF0000">
<input type=text name=password size=20>
</font>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#999999">
&nbsp; 
</td>
<td bgcolor="#999999">
<font size="4" color="#FF0000"><input type=button value="Сгенерировать пароль" onClick="document.myform.password.value =
getPassword(document.myform.passwordLength.value, document.myform.extraChars.value,
document.myform.firstNumber.checked, document.myform.firstLower.checked,
document.myform.firstUpper.checked, document.myform.firstOther.checked,
document.myform.latterNumber.checked, document.myform.latterLower.checked,
document.myform.latterUpper.checked, document.myform.latterOther.checked);" style="font-size: 8pt; font-family: Arial">
&nbsp;
</font>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>
```

1.js

```
function getRandomNum(lbound, ubound) {
    return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (ubound - lbound)) + lbound);
}

function getRandomChar(number, lower, upper, other, extra) {
    var numberChars = "0123456789";
    var lowerChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var upperChars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    var otherChars = "`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+***91;{***93;}\\|;:'\",<.>/? ";
    var charSet = extra;
    if (number == true) charSet += numberChars;
    if (lower == true) charSet += lowerChars;
    if (upper == true) charSet += upperChars;
    if (other == true) charSet += otherChars;
    return charSet.charAt(getRandomNum(0, charSet.length));
}

function getPassword(length, extraChars, firstNumber, firstLower, firstUpper, firstOther, latterNumber, latterLower, latterUpper, latterOther) {
    var rc = "";
    if (length > 0) rc = rc + getRandomChar(firstNumber, firstLower, firstUpper, firstOther, extraChars);
    for (var idx = 1; idx < length; ++idx) {
        rc = rc + getRandomChar(latterNumber, latterLower, latterUpper, latterOther, extraChars);
    }
    return rc;
}
```

Все, что нужно из кода, это чтобы он открыл новую страницу и вывел страницу со значением генератора. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А цель всей этой махинации подскажите пожалуйста?

Comment: Вы хотите сгенерировать адрес вида `http://i32^dF{.ru` ? Можете объяснить доходчивее?

Comment: нет,хочу сделать http://мой сайт.ру/i32^dF{

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getRandomNum(lbound, ubound) {
    return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (ubound - lbound)) + lbound);
}

 function getRandomChar(number, lower, upper, other, extra) {
        var numberChars = "0123456789";
        var lowerChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        var upperChars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        var otherChars = "`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+***91;{***93;}\\|;:'\",<.>/? ";
        var charSet = extra;
        if (number == true) charSet += numberChars;
        if (lower == true) charSet += lowerChars;
        if (upper == true) charSet += upperChars;
        if (other == true) charSet += otherChars;
        return charSet.charAt(getRandomNum(0, charSet.length));
    }
    function openRandPage()
    {
        var url = 'http://мой сайт.ру/';
        for(var i=0;i<10;i++){url+=getRandomChar(true, true, true, true, true)}
        window.open(url, 'newWindow')
    }
    openRandPage(); // запуск функции, можно повесить на онклик
```

Comment: То есть теперь, при вставке этого кода, измененного к url/ будет добавлено значени `getRandomChar` (значение генератора)?

Comment: Я не проверял работоспособность кода. Главная суть - сформировать случайную абракадабру. С этим отлично справляется функция getrandomChar, которая использует getRandomNum.
По одному символу добавить к урл и открыть в новом окне.

P.S. код работает. Одна опечатка была, теперь исправлено

Comment: Работает замечательно, но в конце не приписывает значение после адреса url/***

Comment: Работает, все просто супер! Спасибо за помощь. )

Comment: `var charSet = extra;` - может, `var charSet = '';` ?

Comment: Спасибо за помощь ) Теперь все работает!

Comment: а что значит у меня в инфо -1 и корректор???